# Immediately read an element's visual properties after a CSS change?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change an element on an HTML page using CSS and then immediately read its visual properties. The CSS-enforced style isn't applied until later (next 'frame'), however.

CSS:

```
.node {
    width: 10px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
// Create element
var element = document.createElement("div");
element.className = "node";
document.body.appendChild(element);

console.log(element.clientWidth);
```

The output of the `log` call above should be `10`, but it's `NaN` if called immediately (but it is correctly read as `10` after a frame).

Using `getComputedStyle()` gives similar results:

```
var style = getComputedStyle(element);
console.log(element.style);
```

The output is "" at first run, but "10px" (correctly) after the first frame.

I'm assuming I have to wait once for the browser's re-layout until I can read the property. Is there a way to force the browser to calculate that element's dimensions? Or maybe that would be bad practice; is there a straightforward way to read the CSS's width property?

Put other way, what's the best practice here?

Notes: trying to avoid using jQuery or other libraries here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try accessing the `computedStyle` instead.

```
var computedStyle = document.defaultView ? document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, null) : element.currentStyle;
```

and then read

```
console.log( computedStyle.width);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mGCT5/1/

Comment: Check the browser support for this feature. IE9+ only https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle

Comment: Sorry, I should have added to the question at first: getComputedStyle().width gives similar results - empty at first, working one frame later. Edited to add that. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @zeh: I added a fiddle, works fine for me in IE7+ / FireFox and Chrome at least.

Comment: @jAndy - you are right. I created a new fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/tjfFr/) and... it works as expected; `clientWidth` is even updated after `getComputedStyle()`, which probably forces the browser layout on that div. It must be something else on my code (which is a bit bigger than what's here) that's breaking it for some reason. The funny thing is, the computed style's `width` in my original code works in Firefox (tested just now) but not in Chrome, which is my main test browser.

Comment: Follow up, FWIW: it was not working because `element` wasn't actually added to `document` until later in the code. `getComputedStyle()` and `clientWidth` only work as intended *after* the element has been properly added to the display list. Sounds somewhat obvious in retrospect.

Comment: @zeh: probably call `.appendChild` better on `document.body` instead the `document` itself.

Comment: Yeah, in my code the `appendChild()` call is done to another child element. The code in the question is simplified so I guess the `appendChild()` call there is incorrect. I've fixed it now just for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

You're right in saying that the browser must perform a reflow before you can determine the effects of the changed property (and thus read the changed values). As I'm sure you know, JavaScript is executed by the browser's internal *event loop*. The reflow won't be performed until **after** the current event's JS code has been fully executed.

To solve you problem, you can use [`setImmediate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setImmediate). This allows you to queue a new event which is to be handled *as soon as possible*. You essentially "yield", allow the reflow to occur, and jump back in to finish the rest of your code:

```
var element = document.createElement("div");
element.className = "node";
document.appendChild(element);

setImmediate(function() {
    console.log(element.clientWidth);
});
```

Note that, as of yet, very few popular browsers support `setImmediate`. As a workaround, you can use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) with a delay of `0`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(element.clientWidth);
}, 0);
```

Here is a working example: [jsbin.com/ehigor](http://jsbin.com/ehigor/edit)

Also keep in mind that any code you put after the `setTimeout` block will be executed before the code inside the block, before the end of the current 'frame', and therefore before the reflow.

**Update:**

[jAndy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11453715/990877) is right; `getComputedStyle` will solve OP's problem. In this case, a reflow is not needed, because all you want to do is read the CSS property as it was set.

The reason `getComputedStyle` is needed for this is because the style rule wasn't set in JavaScript. Unlike `element.style`, `getComputedStyle` will take into account style rules set in external CSS files and the browser's default style rules as well.

There are cases when `getComputedStyle` is **not** sufficient, and a reflow **is** needed: when the value of the style rule does not directly correlate to the actual, final value of the style. The most notable case is **relative** dimensions and positions. If you set `width` to (for example) `50%`, but you want to read the element's width in **pixels**, you can only find out what that value will be by letting the browser perform a reflow (in which case `setTimeout` is useful). If, on the other hand, you want to know that `width` was set to `"50%"`; use `getComputedStyle`.

Comment: Thanks. The premise of my question is wrong - apparently the browser reflow *is* triggered on `getComputedStyle` - but I'll use this solution in case I can't normally fix whatever's in my code that's preventing the immediate reflow.

Comment: since ECMAscript runs in the the thread + queue than any CSS dependent thing, it should not be necessary to use `setTimeout` or `setImmediate` here.

Comment: @jAndy and `s/than/as/`, presumably? Are you saying, though, that the browser's rendering engine runs in a different thread than the JS event loop? Because I don't think that's the case. Or are you saying that the CSS style rules are applied when the DOM node is created (versus when it is added to the DOM), so that a reflow is not necessary for the CSS property to be read?

Comment: @PPvG: Actually I was saying, execution of ECMAscript code and the CSS engine share the *same* thread, the such called "UI thread". Of course I can't tell how different browsers handle OPs specific issue, but with that in mind all css updates should be immediately available there (as they are, shown in my answer).

Comment: @jAndy: thanks for the feedback; it made me reconsider my answer. You are right in saying the CSS engine and JS share the same thread, but since that thread is an event loop, JavaScript still has to return before the browser can reflow the page. In this case though, a reflow isn't needed.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use setTimeout to wait for half a second before checking the width?

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood the requirement.